# What is best structure of MySQL table relation?

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel, eloquent

i want know best structure of table for my games.

First, basic table is here.

```
user 
--------
id
email
username
password
etc..
--------

cash
--------
id
timestamp
value
type
--------

games
--------
id
timestamp
--------
```

First, games has 5 users.
So, i create relation tables.

```
users_games
--------
id
user_id
game_id
is_winner
```

And, each games winner take other user's cash.
but game master(server) can give bonus cash to users.
so, i change users_games and cash table.

```
users_games
--------
id
user_id
game_id
cash_id
is_winner

cash
--------
id
user_id
timestamp
value
type
```

this is image of table structure
[sql structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DqnVc.png)

This relationship is perfect, i think.
but MySQL is reject foreignkey users_games to cash

```
ERROR 1215 (HY000): Cannot add foreign key constraint
```

the problem is circular relation, i think.

but i want know

1. cash history with each users.
2. cash history with games.
3. game history with each users.
4. cash details with games.

Can you advice to sql table or foreign keys?

Comment: You haven't presented the actual code, but I can give you a hint:  sometimes you need to add foreign key constraints using `alter table` after all tables have been created.

Comment: If you have not assigned 'id' as the primary key in table `cash` (or if you have not assigned 'id' as UNIQUE), then you will not be able to assign 'call_id' in another table as a foreign key to this.